# why is the insertBefore showing error

Tags: javascript

I intend to create a new Div element via javascript, but i am having problem appending my code to the DOM

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="content"></div>
   </div>
  <script>
    var container = document.getElementById('container');

    function divCreate() {

        var newDiv = document.createElement('div');
        var newContent = document.createTextNode('Hello this is 
         
        div via javascript!'); 
                                                               
        newDiv.appendChild(newContent);

        var currentDiv = document.getElementById('content');

        document.body.container.insertBefore(newDiv, currentDiv);
  }
                  
  divCreate();
  </script>
```

my actual intention was to insert the new div before the content inside the container. I do understand the DOM as a tree of objects and hierarchy too.I thought that i could navigate the tree via this hierarchy . that is from document--->body----->container.

It did worked on the container, but not the content div. Could someone please tell what I am missing here?

I did try to append the newDiv to the DOM before the content, but I was unable. I was able to append it to the container DIV which is a parent of the content Div. my main concern is why ami unable to append it before the content using the insert before method.

Comment: update  your question with full html code

Comment: Can you fix the formatting of your code?  You seem to have added newlines in the middle of lines of code and you are missing `)`s.

Comment: You don't need the `document.body` part. You can access the `container` directly.

Answer (score 0):

> I thought that i could navigate the tree via this hierarchy . that is from document--->body----->container.

You can't.

Use `document.getElementById()` to get an element by its ID.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 <div id="container">
    <div id="content">
    </div>
    </div>
    <script>
    var container = document.getElementById('container');
    function divCreate()   {
    var newDiv = document.createElement('div');
    var newContent = document.createTextNode('Hello ....');
    newDiv.appendChild(newContent);
    var currentDiv = document.getElementById('content');    
    document.body.container.insertBefore(newDiv,currentDiv}
    divCreate();    
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="content">
  </div> </div>
  <script>
    var container = document.getElementById('container');

    function divCreate() {

        var newDiv = document.createElement('div');
        var newContent = document.createTextNode('Hello this is a div is added via javascript');   
                                                               
        newDiv.appendChild(newContent);

        var currentDiv = document.getElementById('content');

        container.insertBefore(newDiv, currentDiv);
  }
                  
  divCreate();
  </script>
```